# optimized way to sort array of objects in order of another array values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a array of ids and array of objects.

```
var ids = [4, 2, 5, 8]
var objs = [
            {"id": 2, "name": "a"}, 
            {"id": 4, "name": "b"}, 
            {"id": 8, "name": "c"}, 
            {"id": 5, "name": "d"}
        ]
```

I want to sort `objs` in order of values given in `ids` array.
so sorted objs should be

```
[
    {"id": 4, "name": "a"}, 
    {"id": 2, "name": "b"}, 
    {"id": 5, "name": "c"}, 
    {"id": 8, "name": "d"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map the `ids` array, example:

```js
const ids = [4, 2, 5, 8]
const objs = [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "b"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "c"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "d"
  }
]

const result = ids.map(id => objs.find((o) => o.id == id));
console.log(result);
```

To do this more efficiently, you can use:

```js
const ids = [4, 2, 5, 8]
const objs = [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "b"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "c"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "d"
  }
];

const map = objs.reduce((a, c) => (a[c.id] = c, a),{});

const result = ids.map(id => map[id]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

For all items, you could map the wanted order by using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
var ids = [4, 2, 5, 8],
    array = [{ id: 2, name: "a" }, { id: 4, name: "b" }, { id: 8, name: "c" }, { id: 5, name: "d" }],
    ordered = ids.map(Map.prototype.get, new Map(array.map(o => [o.id, o])));

console.log(ordered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create order to sort:

```
let order = { 4: 1, 2: 2, 5: 3, 8: 4 };
objs.sort(function (a, b) {
  return order[a.id] - order[b.id];
});
```

An example:

```js
var ids = [4, 2, 5, 8]
var objs = [
            {"id": 2, "name": "a"}, 
            {"id": 4, "name": "b"}, 
            {"id": 8, "name": "c"}, 
            {"id": 5, "name": "d"}
        ]

let order = { 4: 1, 2: 2, 5: 3, 8: 4 };


objs.sort(function (a, b) {
  return order[a.id] - order[b.id];
});

console.log(objs);
```